# Recursively calculating the value of the function f = n!/(c^n)

Tags: c++, recursion

I was given this question in a test last week:

```
/* Task 1: Implement the following function for calculating the value of
       the function f = n!/(c^n).
*/

float func(int n, int c) {

}
```

I am attempting to figure out the answer now after the fact because it was something I could not work out during the test (recursion is something I struggle with).

This is my attempt so far:

```
float result = 0;

// n!*c^n-1
float func( int n, int c )
{
    if( n == 0 )
       return result;

    result += n*c;
    return func( n*n-1, pow(c,-n) );
}
```

If anyone could help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: Hint: `n!/(c^n)` == `(n-1)!*n / ( (c^(n-1) * c)`. In other words, `f(n, c) == f(n-1,c)*n/c` . Expressing this in code is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    float result = 1;

// n!*c^n-1
float func( double n, double c )
{
    if( n == 0 )
       return result;

    return func(n-1,c )*(n/c);
}
```

This is the algorythm used to solve this problem
I changed the parameters of the function from int to double because the last line contains (n/c) and integer devision causes wrong answers if c is not a divisor of n

You should notice that `f(n,c) =f(n-1,c)*(n/c)` because `n!=n*(n-1)!`